# Dynamic List Input control in JasperReport 5

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have 100,000 account numbers. I want to randomly give any 5 (as per my requirement. Could be  1 or 2 or 20) account numbers and see the information about them.I have tried the following.

I tried with string input control, cascading input control with one string and one list parameters. But none of them works.

1) String Input Control: I tried entering the 3 random account numbers comma separated. But my query dosent accept the same since I have to use a list parameter and $X variable.
**($X{IN,acct_no,test}).**

2) Cascading Input Control: I thought let me take a string input control and a list list input control and use the string input control within the list input control. So I tried like the following.

- Created a parameter and an input control with string datatype (where I can enter comma separated account numbers). The parameter name is **$P{account_no}**
- Created a list parameter and an input control with list datatype as an multiselect query using the string parameter as below. The parameter name is **$P{test}**

> select account_no from customers where account_no IN (**$P{account_no}**)

Note that I have used the first parameter.
This works fine for only 1 account number and not for **'n'** account numbers.
I also tried something like

```
select account_no from customers where ($X{IN,acct_no,account_no})
```

For obvious reasons this does not work.

I am using **Jasper 5.0.1**

Is there a way to dynamically populate a list based on the input values.

Could anyone kindly let me know how to achieve my desired output?

Any help would be appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick.

SELECT customer_name FROM customers where account_no in($P!{account_no});